# Laravel Failed Jobs to Redis

Tags: php, laravel, redis

I am trying to configure my Laravel app so all my Laravel Queue Failed Jobs goes to Redis instead of mysql.

Currenly my jobs are configured to use redis but failed_jobs still goes to MySql Database

*Didn't find anything on StackOverflow/Laravel*

**Laravel 5.4**

**Redis**

**PHP 7.0**

Please help!

Comment: You need to set failed connection in queue.php file

Answer (score 1):

I think you are trying to use Redis wrong. you should store your failed job in a right database like PostgreSQL or MySQL. Laravel just use Redis for queue as a "Broker" because Redis has [built-in queue data structure](https://redis.com/glossary/event-queue/) and can efficiently handle queues with minimum effort and with high performance. consider to store your failures and results of them in a separated database for examine them later.

Comment: For a big job processing, we need to monitor a large of failed jobs, redis do this job effectively but MySQL got connection limits and hence crashes. At that time, I posted question, 5years and 8 months ago, I didn't find any solution.

Answer (score -1):

To configure Laravel so that failed jobs are stored in Redis instead of MySQL, you need to make a few changes in your Laravel application.

1. **Update the Failed Job Database Connection**: By default, Laravel stores failed jobs in the database connection specified in your `.env` file. To change this, open the `config/queue.php` file and locate the `failed` configuration array. Update the `database` key to use the Redis connection instead. For example:

```php
'failed' => [
    'database' => 'redis', // Update this to use the Redis connection
],
```

2. **Create the Failed Jobs Table in Redis**: Laravel requires a table to store failed jobs, even if you're using Redis. To create this table in Redis, run the following command in your terminal:

```bash
php artisan queue:failed-table
```

This command will create a migration file for the failed jobs table. Now, run the migration to create the table in Redis:

```bash
php artisan migrate
```

3. **Update the Queue Worker Configuration**: By default, Laravel's queue worker will use the `database` connection to process failed jobs. To change this, open the `config/queue.php` file again and locate the `connections` array. Update the `redis` connection to include the `failed` configuration. For example:

```php
'redis' => [
    'driver' => 'redis',
    'connection' => 'default',
    'queue' => env('REDIS_QUEUE', 'default'),
    'retry_after' => 90,
    'block_for' => null,
    'failed' => [
        'database' => 'redis', // Update this to use the Redis connection
    ],
],
```

4. **Restart the Queue Worker**: After making these changes, restart your queue worker to apply the new configuration. Run the following command in your terminal:

```bash
php artisan queue:restart
```

Now, when a job fails, it will be stored in the Redis database instead of MySQL.

Note: Make sure you have the Redis driver installed and properly configured in your Laravel application. You can check the `config/database.php` file to ensure the Redis configuration is correct.

I hope this helps!

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831/11107541

Answer (score -2):

Check your settings in `config/queue.php`, you should find following values:

```
'failed' => [
    'database' => env('DB_CONNECTION', 'mysql'),
    'table' => env('QUEUE_FAILED_TABLE', 'failed_jobs'),
]
```

Change the connection and table on whatever you need.

Comment: I think that laravel redis driver don't configured to store failed jobs info. I use postgre and it works fine.

I also tried to change config and find failed jobs info in redis, but unsuccessful.

So I suppose there are no way to store failed_jobs in key value storage. It requires relational database with tables, config file values allude to that. And if think about it, why are we trying to put failed_jobs to redis? I just stick with postgre ...

Comment: Should work by changing it to Redis. Also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39487252/redis-queue-failed-job-is-being-logged-to-mysql

Comment: This is the exact same wrong answer as linked in the comment by rhand